# How to get result of querySuccess in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I need to get result to var in javascript of querySuccess in phonegap
this is my code

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DMOMM1', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
```

I need this 'message'

```
    var message = results.rows.item(0).data;

}

function errorCB(err) {
 alert( "Error" );

}

function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            console.log('succesCB');
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(successCB);
   console.log('oDevReady');
}
function onSuccess(position) {
 $.get('http://adress.com/coord.php?      name=
```

I need to put here 'message'

```
 &lati='+position.coords.latitude+'&longi='+position.coords.longitude);
  }
 function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

can you say where I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `var message;` outside of a function (instead of inside a function as you have above) and then in the function use:

```
message = results.rows.item(0).data;
```

instead of

```
var message = results.rows.item(0).data;
```

This is a scoping issue.